# Can't write to shared folder in Windows 2012 domain .. sometimes

Tags: windows, permissions, network-shares, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I have issue with Windows Server 2012 domain network share, I can easily create network share and add permissions for connecting to share, but when it comes to writing(ex. creating directories) it does not seem to accept my security access rights at all.

Test user account: Kokeilu (kokeilu)

After lot of testing I noticed if I map the shared network drive for Kokeilu several times, it has about 50% changes to give my test user Kokeilu write access but on other times only read access. If I map the network drive using Kokeilu's credentials with and without domain name it always fails to give write access.

I have checked that without giving credentials it will map the Kokeilu account with command:

```
wmic netuse where LocalName="Z:" get UserName /value
```

Which returns correct user:

```
UserName=DOMAIN.LOCAL\kokeilu
```

Now I am giving pretty much everything full access on Security window and advanced settings, setting owner to Kokeilu, using effective rights check on advanced settings it tells me that Kokeilu has full access to everything.

I even got error while renaming folder which told me that you need to ask Kokeilu to give you access to this folder when Kokeilu was already owner of that folder with full rights.

There seems to be some issues with Active Directory / Network drive sharing, I wonder how to start finding those issues?

Network drive which I am testing is mapped to one of the Domain Controllers, the DC has several other shared drives too, and they work normally atm, I haven't tried disconnecting and reconnecting them, but they seem to work better, than this newly created share.

If I give Kokeilu Domain Admin -rights, write and everything start to work how they should but plan is to create some private user specific folders.

Shared folder is virtual hard drive on another physical medium than Domain controller which is virtual machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why I was able to sometimes write to shared folder with test user Kokeilu, but I was mainly editing security options from another computer which was not sharing the folder. When I went back to Domain Controller which is sharing the folder, there was messagebox saying that F:\recycle bin is corrupted (in the shared folder). After that I checked permissions from advanced sharing and there was only read access to Authenticated users, I changed that to full access and after that I meddled with folder specific security settings and now it seems I am able to set user specific settings.